# Ionic2 ion-item-sliding not working with *ngFor dynamic list

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

ionic-angular version is 2.0.0-rc.2

if I remove *ngFor, using a static list instead, it works fine. The following is the code snippet.

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items">
        <ion-item>
            <h2>{{item.subject}}</h2>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item-options side="right">
            <button ion-button color="primary">
                <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon> Email
            </button>
        </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: does it show an error?

Comment: @SurajRao no error. Seems someone has the same problem. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/9095

Answer (score 0):

I notice problem with ion-item-sliding, when slide, it not keep slided item, so not allows to click ion-item-options button

Answer (score 0):

The above code is tested and finally has run successfully with dynamic data from outside.

The problem is that when item is calling just add the little code. async pipe after the loop.

The Final code will be....

```
 <ion-list>
      <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items  | async">
          <ion-item>
              <h2>{{item.subject}}</h2>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item-options side="right">
              <button ion-button color="primary">
                  <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon> Email
              </button>
          </ion-item-options>
      </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
```

Hopefully, Above code will work fine.

Comment: This doesn't help... at least in my case.

Comment: @shane, remove `async` then take a look